# Nginx proxy_pass to upstream uses sometimes IPv6 address

Tags: linux, nginx, ipv6

Why does Nginx proxy_pass to upstream send sometimes outgoing requests to IPv6?

```
2015/12/28 14:11:06 [error] 38194#0: *114469948 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /suggest/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[AAAA:BBB:CCC:DDDD::E]:5555/suggestion", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/en/apple-111111/"
```

nginx.conf:

```
location /suggest/ {
    proxy_pass http://testserver.com:5555/suggestion;
    proxy_set_header Authorization 'Basic xxx';
}
```

Instead of sending the request to our testserver.com the request goes to http://[AAAA:BBB:CCC:DDDD::E]:5555/suggest

Does anybody know where the IPv6 address is coming from or what is wrong with the nginx conf?

Thanks in advice,
Hans

Here is a real example:

```
2015/12/28 14:11:03 [error] 38192#0: *114552633 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xxx, server: pixabay.com, request: "POST /suggest/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[2a01:4f8:160:4450::2]:5555/pixabay/suggestion", host: "pixabay.com", referrer: "https://pixabay.com/fr/"
```

And the nginx.conf:

```
location /suggest/ {
  proxy_pass http://pagewizz.com:5555/pixabay/suggestion;
  proxy_set_header Authorization 'Basic xxx';
}
```

We are running a big image datebase called Pixabay. For searching we use elasticsearch which is running on another server called Pagewizz (2a01:4f8:160:4450::2). If somebody is tagging images, we use elastic to get suggestions. I have no clue why the ipv6 address of Pagewizz appears in the error logs of nginx...

Comment: Please provide the _real_ information.

Comment: The ipv6 address should be the address of the server, more details are required of your v6 config.

Comment: OK, that is happening because Pagewizz isn't listening on 2a01:4f8:160:4450::2 port 5555.